# Not able to scrape embedded YouTube video from website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this(marked in red in attached image) embedded YouTube video from " [https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/86/Ferrari/458-Italia-458-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=70&yearId=3945"](https://www.akrapovic.com/en/car/product/86/Ferrari/458-Italia-458-Spider/Slip-On-Line-Titanium?brandId=20&modelId=70&yearId=3945%22) but am not able to find its source or any YouTube link to scrape.

Code I've written to get is as follows. Unfortunately, all it does is throws an 'NoSuchElementException'.Please suggest me best way to go about with this. Thanks in advance.

```
driver.get(part_page_link_holder3)
video_holder = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'video-fullscreen')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", video_holder)
video_holder2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//iframe')
print(video_holder2)
```

[image]

Comment: You can show part of your code and the error you are getting. That will help anyone to know how to answer your question. Secondly, I have observed that some website use advanced data protection mechanism which will make their website impossible to scrape.

Comment: I've just linked the code I am using to make it work.

Comment: Upto which point does it work? Does the click work? Is it not able to find the iframe?

Comment: It was able to find video-fullscreen but nothing works after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is visible in the code after looking through inspect. It only shows up after clicking the play button on the video though.

[image]

Comment: Yup found it but still have no idea how to scrape it.